# Why do we not see spiritual powers run in human families?

Tags: bleach

It's shown that spiritual powers run in families. And that the types of power that a human can have varies- Chad, Orihime, the Fullbringers, whatever was going on with Ururu and Jinta. So **why is it that beyond seeing ghosts, only Quincy/Shinigami powers seem to get passed on from generation to generation?**

Beyond the whole "Karakura is the setting" thing, why do we not even hear about this being possible? Shinigami patrol the Living World: would they not have even rumors of this (at least among Division 12)?

Comment: Are you asking why the only familial lines we see are Shinigami and Quincy? What do you mean by "this being possible"? Are you referring to other powers passing down through family lines?

Comment: Yes, I'm asking why humans with spiritual abilities don't seem to pass them down to their kids unless they're Quincies, and why it never gets even an off-hand remark from anyone (like the shinigami) who would have witnessed such a thing.

Comment: the answer to most questions in the Bleach universe is probably either Aizen did it, or Juchabach did it. They are the ultimate DEMs. Why is it that only Quincy have inheritable spiritual powers? Juchabach.

Answer (score 3):

Fullbring is not a genetic trait, being a Quincy is one.

A person get [Fullbring](http://thebleachfanon.wikia.com/wiki/Fullbringer) if his/her mother survives a Hollow attack while being pregnant with the person. Period. The actual manifestation of the power is, like all almost super powers in Bleach, only limited by what Tite Kubo could think of.

I don't know what's the deal with Shinigami families, though. And Hollow families are even more complicated, because they fuse from time to time.

Then there is the Dragon Ball, err, the [Hougyoku](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/H%C5%8Dgyoku). Grants deepest desires. Orohime's power comes from that. In fact we do not now if it is know genetically anchored within her.

**So besides Quincy/Shinigami and maybe Hollow powers, simply no genetically anchored powers are shown in the series.**